# I want to Ignore a Specific Entity from being @Transactional (using Spring/Hibernate)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-transactions

I run a SpringMVC application and I'm using the @Transactional annotations in conjunction with a HibernateTransactionManager.

As a result, anywhere in my application that I throw a RuntimeException, we roll back- this is great! Everything works perfectly.

But now I'd like to **exclude a single Entity from the Transactionality**.  This Entity represents something that I want persisted (benchmarks/logs/errors) even if (*especially if*) there is a RuntimeException which marks everything else for Rollback.

I'd rather not have to call some repository from outside of my Interceptor which begins and ends the Transaction.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An entity is not transactional. A method is.

If you want some part of your algorithm to not be part of the current transaction, then put that part in a method of a separate bean, and annotate it with `@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)`, so that a dedicated, separate transaction is opened and committed when invoking this method, unaffected by the outcome of the current transaction.